# hide toggle content, if a user didnt click inside a specific box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for toggling menus on my site. It will open a menu on click, close others open when you click another and close them all if you click outside.

The issue is, I'm now using this for my search bar to appear too, but if you click inside the search box it vanishes - woops. Would it be possible to amend the hiding code to detect if the user **wasn't** clicking inside a specific area of the code?

```
  // navbar toggle menu
    $(document).on('click', ".toggle-nav > a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $toggle = $(this).closest('.toggle-nav').children('.toggle-content');
    if ($toggle.hasClass('toggle-active'))
    {
      $($toggle).removeClass('toggle-active');
    }
    else
    {
      $(".toggle-content").removeClass('toggle-active');
      $($toggle).addClass('toggle-active');
    }
  });

    // hide the toggle-nav if you click outside of it
    $(document).on("click", function ()
    {
        $(".toggle-content").removeClass('toggle-active');
    });
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the HTML and CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `click`, this uses `mouseup`. If the target is, for example `#search-bar`, it won't remove toggle-active from toggle-content elements.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('#search-bar')) {
             $(".toggle-content").removeClass('toggle-active');
        }
});
```

You can see it in action with this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Ln3oc90/).

Hopefully this helps.